# How to read csv file with string but convert to different type and send to an array in python?

Tags: python

I have a csv file, contain datetime, number1, number2, number3 number4.

I use code to read, but how to change the types.

my code:

```
import csv
import datetime
myarray=([])
filename='Contract.csv'
f=csv.reader(open(filename,'rb'), delimiter=',')
for row in f:
    myarray=array([row for row in f])
print myarray
```

I get the array looks like:
[['2010-05-01 15:20:12 0000' '345' '234' '163' '120'],
 ['2010-05-02 15:22:12 0000' '335' '214' '164' '120'],
...
]

I have no idea how to change the first column into datetime and the others into float.
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python).

Having said that. I use a function like this one (requries [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)) to manage dates too:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as date_parser
def _cast_value(self, value):
    tests = (
        int,
        float,
        lambda value: date_parser(value)
    )
    for test in tests:
        try:
            return test(value)
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return value
```

`dateutil` will handle different kind of date formats for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the values:

```
i=int(s)
dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d ...')
```